# Converting url encode data from curl to json object in python using requests

Tags: python, http-post, python-requests

What is the best way to convert the below curl post into python request using the requests module:

```
curl -X POST https://api.google.com/gmail --data-urlencode json='{"user": [{"message":"abc123", "subject":"helloworld"}]}'
```

I tried using python requests as below, but it didn't work:

```
payload = {"user": [{"message":"abc123", "subject":"helloworld"}]}
url = https://api.google.com/gmail
requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload),auth=(user, password))
```

Can anybody help.

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? And you should set the `url` variable to be a string, not just some url. Surround it with `"`

Answer (score 0):

As the comment mentioned, you should put your `url` variable string in quotes `""` first.

Otherwise, your question is not clear. What errors are being thrown and/or behavior is happening?

[New cURL method in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936555/how-to-construct-the-curl-command-from-python-requests-module)

Comment: it says returned nothing in payload

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes? Check out the link above for a newer way to use cURL in Python.