# Python Requests to cURL?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I have a python snippet for a posting a file onto an URL:

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.test.com/route'
files = {'pdf': open('/path/to/file/abc.pdf', 'rb'), 'variable_1': '1', 'variable_2': '2'}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
print(r.status_code)
```

It works! And I am looking for the cURL equivalent for the same!

I have tried this:

```
curl -X POST   http://www.test.com/route   -H 'content-type: application/json'   -F pdf=@/path/to/file/abc.pdf   -F variable_1=1   -F variable_2=2
```

What would be the correct curl? Thanks!

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936555/how-to-construct-the-curl-command-from-python-requests-module) and [here](https://github.com/oeegor/curlify)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to construct the curl command from python requests module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936555/how-to-construct-the-curl-command-from-python-requests-module)

Comment: @Iguananaut- Nope

Comment: Why do you have headers in `curl`?