# How to get api req as cURL and print on terminal using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, playwright-python

I am trying to scrap a website by intercepting http network calls using `playwright` python module.

I want to get the cURL from network call.

something like this, we do it manually. To copy the cURL of API call.

[image]

How can I get the cURL text and print on terminal?

Here is my attempt.

```py
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

def scrape_graphql_response():
    with sync_playwright() as pw:
        browser = pw.chromium.launch(
            headless=False,
            slow_mo=1000,
        )

        context = browser.new_context(
            viewport={"width": 1920, "height": 1080}
        )
        page = context.new_page()

        # Enable request interception
        page.route('**/graphql', lambda route: route.continue_())

        # Navigate to your website
        page.goto('https://example.com')  #sample url for website home page

        # Wait for the GraphQL request to complete
        with page.expect_request('**/graphql') as req:
            # Access the GraphQL response
            print(req.value)

        # Close the browser
        browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrape_graphql_response()
```

I am getting this. which is not a cURL.
`<Request url='https://www.threads.net/api/graphql' method='POST'>`

Answer (score 0):

"Copy as" is a browser feature, the browser takes all the parameters and presents them in a way that you can use to replay the request. If you want the same in python you have to build it yourself, since you have a Request object you can get all the data and build a curl/fetch/HAR or whatever you need yourself. [Check here for someone with the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17936555/how-to-construct-the-curl-command-from-python-requests-module)

Top 2 answers are both ways to achieve what you want, with an external module and with your own code.